# "-ftrapv" and "-fwrapv": Which is better for efficiency?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu, integer-overflow

From GNU's website:

> - `-ftrapv`
>
>   This option generates traps for signed overflow on addition, subtraction, multiplication operations.
> - `-fwrapv`
>
> This option instructs the compiler to assume that signed arithmetic overflow of addition, subtraction and multiplication wraps around using twos-complement representation. This flag enables some optimizations and disables others.
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

I have two questions:

1. Which of these options is better for performance?
2. What what does it mean when the `-ftrapv` definition says it generates "traps?" Does this mean exceptions? (I'm guessing no, but it's worth asking.)

Comment: "_Which is faster?_" - Measure it with your code. I assume it highly depends on the application.

Comment: Not needing to test for overflowing would be preferred.

Comment: Neither of these is intended as a performance booster. If you're using these for performance, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not trying to use it as a performance booster per se, I'm just asking about their efficiency in general @hvd

Comment: @user743382 very WRONG, the whole point of -fwrapv is to turn off optimisations that break the Twos complement definition (by the CPU maker) of signed integer instructions. The whole reason for optimisation is to boost performance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *whole point* of both of these options is to give the optimiser *less* leeway than it normally has. Therefore, unless you encounter a bug in the optimiser, the fastest should be to use neither, where the optimiser assumes your code doesn't have any overflows and doesn't emit code to handle overflows.

> What what does it mean when the -ftrapv definition says it generates "traps?" Does this mean exceptions?

It doesn't mean a C++ exception. It's target-dependent, but assuming x86, it means the GCC runtime libraries cause SIGABRT to be raised that will normally abort your program. On other platforms, it might use special CPU instructions that cause a hardware exception. It's mainly useful for debugging purposes and perhaps in a few cases for safety, where the risk of continuing after overflow is greater than the risk of the program suddenly terminating.

Comment: The problem isn't "emit code to handle overflows", since all extant machines are two's complement. It's, instead, missed optimization opportunities, for some special cases. But, there's an option to tell it to optimize loops anyway (sorry I don't remember the option name).

Comment: Also, I doubt the documentation is so bad that it replaces "aborts" with "traps". A trap means a (usually) hardware level exception. It can be handled in platform-specific ways.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It was mainly for `-ftrapv`, but even for `-fwrapv`, there can be extra instructions: additions that otherwise get optimised away. That's what you're saying too, I think, just from a different point of view, I'm taking the optimised code as the baseline, you're taking the unoptimised code as the baseline. As for exceptions, I got the impression the OP was asking about C++ exceptions, not hardware exceptions. But you're right that the hardware exceptions can be handled, I should edit to cover that.

Comment: At least on Linux, the observable effect of `-ftrapv` is your process gets `SIGFPE` when such an overflow occurs. It's mainly useful for debugging - nice to have it on for CI, for instance.

Comment: "assuming x86, it means the GCC runtime libraries cause SIGABRT" - that's assuming x86 AND *nix...

Answer (score 4):

`-ftrapv` is the slowest since it needs to add extra code to detect and trap overflow on almost every operation on signed integers, except where the compiler has enough information about the value range to prove the operation doesn't overflow.

`-fwrapv` is probably the next slowest, since it prohibits certain optimizations that assume values never wrap, but this impact is fairly small, so the performance of `-fwrapv` will usually be similar or even identical to not providing either of these options.

Answer (score 2):

Optimal performance will be achieved if there is a way to tell the compiler that in case of overflow it may freely select from among all the possible behaviors *that will meet application requirements*.  Treating overflow as UB will only yield optimal behavior if a programmer can be so certain that the program will never receive any inputs that cause overflow that even the most deliberately-capricious overflow behavior imaginable would meet requirements.

In cases where it would be acceptable to have a compiler arbitrarily choose from among a large number of possible outputs, provided that overall behavior remains constrained, making overflow UB is likely to yield a worst-of-all-worlds combination of source code complexity and run-time performance compared with -fwrapv, since a programmer would have to specify in source code all of the operations that the compiler would auto-generate for -fwrapv.  The performance would be inferior to what could be achieved with a less aggressive optimizer that was designed around the idea of "yield arbitrary data, but constrained behavior", but gcc offers no such options.

Trapping overflow in the compiler is apt to be much more expensive than letting overflowed computations wrap (or--if the compiler permits--let them be treated as having arbitrary extended precision that might behave in non-deterministic fashion), but may sometimes be cheaper than trapping overflows manually in code.  Whether trapping overflow in the compiler is useful will depend upon whether application requirements demand it.