# Can I get an interrupt/segfault on int overflow on either x86-64 or ARM?

Tags: assembly, exception, arm, x86-64, interrupt

I have two toy assembly programs. x86-64 and ARM8

I'd like to write a loop that adds 1<<62 into an accumulator and overflow the int (should be 5 or less iterations depending if it overflows on sign or unsigned). Is it possible to have the hardware interrupt or crash my program when it overflows? Looking at the linked page there's a number of exceptions that happen based on segments. I was wondering if that'd be how I'd do it? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add

I don't mind when the crash happens, can be 8 bit overflow, 32, signed, unsigned, whatever. On x84-64 or ARM.

Comment: You could try compiling with GCC/clang's `-ftrapv` option and see what they produce.

Comment: x86 does not do automatic overflow checking. You can add code manually if you want, but for that you need to know the exact place you expect overflow to happen.

Comment: On x86, you have to manually use [`into`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) ("generate overflow trap if OF is set") after `add` or other instructions you want to check for overflow.  That will emulate the behaviour of MIPS `add` (as opposed to `addu`), trapping on signed overflow.  If you want to trap on CF (unsigned wraparound), use `jc` to branch to whatever instruction you want, like `ud2` illegal-instruction.  (This also works with `jo` for signed overflow, like `clang -ftrapv` does, as @AndrewHenle recommended:  https://godbolt.org/z/zK1c3T3eo)

Comment: `into` does not work in 64 bit mode though.

Comment: Usually you 'branch on overflow'.  It is not clear what you gain by having an interrupt?  I think the divide by zero interrupt is the mistake; there could be a flag for that.  ARM has [saturating instructions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/saturating-instructions) which is one way to handle this use case.  The value could signed or unsigned, so an generic overflow interrupt is not too meaningful.  `bcs overflow_exit`.. also some instruction may not set carry nor signed overflow. Better done by a compiler for instruction selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960763/ftrapv-and-fwrapv-which-is-better-for-efficiency  I will close automatically if I vote that; but I think it is a duplicate.  With twos complement add/sub, etc are the same operations.  So notationally, something else has to be aware of what an overflow is.  It is also perfectly fine for a CRC (or GF2 coding).

Comment: This does exist for floating-point math.  In principle, you could double a number (i.e. increment the exponent) until overflow, or add 1 until inexact.  Probably not actually useful, though.